# Pointer to array of struct in function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I had a problem with the pointers. I wanna read a binary file with a function, and then, use the read data in the main. The problem is that I had to pass a pointer to array of struct to can use the data in main.

The code is:

```
#define TMOLDEO 8
#define TAM 41


struct fichpiezas{
    int codPieza;
    float dimPieza;
    float costePieza[TMOLDEO];
};

int leer_fichero(struct fichpiezas *vpiezas[]);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    struct fichpiezas vpiezas[TAM];

    leer_fichero(&vpiezas);

    for(int i = 0; sizeof(vpiezas)/sizeof(struct fichpiezas); i++){
        printf("Codigo pieza : %d\n", vpiezas[i].codPieza);
    }

    return 0;
}


int leer_fichero (struct fichpiezas *vpiezas[]){

    FILE *fich;
    struct fichpiezas pieza;
    int error_dev = 0, i = 0;
    if ((fich = fopen("piezas.bin", "rb")) == NULL){
        printf ( "Error en apertura del fichero para lectura \n " );
        error_dev = 1;
    } else{
        //Bucle mientras no sea fin de fichero
        while (! feof(fich)){
            fread (&pieza, sizeof(pieza), 1, fich);
            vpiezas[i] = &pieza;
            i++;
        }

        fclose (fich);
    }

    return error_dev;
}
```

Comment: Code/comments in English will generally make it easier to read, but `pieza` in `leer_fichero` has local storage, and you just keep putting that one address into your array, and that object will be out of scope after the end of the functions.

Comment: this line: 'for(int i = 0; sizeof(vpiezas)/sizeof(struct fichpiezas); i++){' in main() has a problem.  it does not ever exit the for loop because the calculation is always the same.  suggest: 'for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(vpiezas)/sizeof(struct fichpiezas)); i++){'  Note: the value of the calculation will always be 'TAM'

Comment: this line: 'while (! feof(fich)){' will not work as expected because feof() is not defined until after a read operation from the fich file..  suggest using: 'while( fread (&pieza, sizeof(pieza), 1, fich)   ) '  fread will return the third parameter on success and (in this case) 0 when failure/EOF occurs.

Comment: this line: 'vpiezas[i] = &pieza;  passes the same address every time.  suggest: 'memcpy( &(vpiezas[i]),  &pieza, sizeof(struct fichpiezas) ); ''

Comment: this line: 'int leer_fichero (struct fichpiezas *vpiezas[]){' indicates passing an array of pointers, when actually only one pointer to an array of structs is involved. suggest: 'int leer_fichero (struct fichpiezas *vpiezas){'

Comment: the function: leer_fichero, while loop should be checking the value of 'i' to exit the loop when the callers' array of structs if full.  suggest: 'if( i>=TAM) break;'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change this

```
int leer_fichero (struct fichpiezas *vpiezas[])
```

to

```
int leer_fichero (struct fichpiezas *vpiezas)
```

and in your `main()`

```
leer_fichero(&vpiezas);
```

to

```
leer_fichero(vpiezas);
```

the array will automatically decay to a pointer when passed to the function. So you don't need to pass it's address to the function.

You have another problem, this assignment

```
vpiezas[i] = &pieza;
```

is a problem, because you are storing the address of the local variable `pieza` in the array, and the data will be gone when this function returns.

Aditionally the value of `pieza` is being overwritten in each iteration bu `fread()` and since you store the address of `pieza` instead of it's value, all the elements of the array will have the same value if it succeeded this way.

You need to copy the struct into the array element, and this line if you follow my advice above should change to

```
vpiezas[i] = pieza;
```

or the program will fail to compile, because the type of `&pieza` is `struct fichpiezas *` and that of `vpiezas[i]` now is `struct fichpiezas` after changing the function prototype.

Also, about `while (! feof(fich))` there was an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26557243/1983495) which explains in detail why that is wrong.

And one more thing, add a check `i < TAM` because you are in risk of overflowing the array otherwise.

Comment: or `int leer_fichero (struct fichpiezas vpiezas[])`

Comment: Thank you! I going to prove it.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
int leer_fichero(struct fichpiezas * vpiezas[]);
```

defines `vpiezas` to be a pointer to a pointer to `struct fichpiezas`, as

```
int leer_fichero(struct fichpiezas * vpiezas[]);
```

is equivalent to

```
int leer_fichero(struct fichpiezas ** vpiezas);
```

To address the elements of the array you pass by doing

```
leer_fichero(&vpiezas);
```

do like this

```
(*vpiezas)[index]
```

inside of `leer_fichero()`.

---

It would be more straight forward to define

```
int leer_fichero(struct fichpiezas * vpiezas);
```

and pass

```
leer_fichero(vpiezas);
```

then you can address the elements as you do:

```
vpiezas[index]
```

Comment: `int leer_fichero(struct fichpiezas * vpiezas[]);` does not "define `vpiezas` to be a pointer to a pointer to `struct fichpiezas`". It defines `vpiezas` to be (used in the function as) an array of pointers to `struct fichpiezas`. Otherwise, your solution works, but your first proposal would be clearer, if you also proposed to change the definition of the function to `int leer_fichero(struct fichpiezas (*vpiezas)[]);`, or simply `int leer_fichero(struct fichpiezas **vpiezas);`, for clarity reasons, when using `(*vpiezas)[index]` for access.

Comment: @kavadias: Please see my updated answer, especially please note that in the context of defining function parameters in C `char []` is equivalent to `char *`, as well as `char *[]` being equivalent to `char **` ...

Comment: @kavadias: Also please note that any array passed to a function decays to a pointer to is 1st element.

Comment: You are right! I thought that there would be an error, if the function was declared as, e.g., `int leer_fichero (struct fichpiezas vpiezas[TAM+1])`, calling it like `leer_fichero(vpiezas);` in main, but I was wrong. An array argument is a declaration --not a definition-- of an array, so it is always, simply, a pointer; whereas inside function or global scope it is always a definition (unless `extern` is used).